# Using the row position in an sapply function

Tags: r

This question is about `sapply` accessing the row number, of the row it's working on. I'm trying to use sapply (or whatever apply is applicable) instead of a loop. However, I need knowledge of which **row** I am working on during the `apply`. I can rewrite this, but I would like to do it with an apply function.

*Finance: In a recombining binomial tree u >1, and d=1/u are multipliers to a stock price. To find the price at time n, you multiply: time zero price, u^#movements up, d^#of movements down. #down+#up=n*

```
s_t = function(s_tm, tree_path, move_ratio, u_or_d ='u'){
    u.z = move_ratio
    if (u_or_d == 'd') { u.z = 1/move_ratio }
    ud_coeff = u.z ^ (tree_path[1]-tree_path[2])
    s_tm * ud_coeff }
```

This `s_t` will be the `FUN` function fed to `sapply`. the variable `tree_path` is a tuple/vector (#up,#down). For any time t, they always sum to the same number. However, I need #up and #down to change for each node in the tree.

Example: S0 = 100, u=1.25 d=1/u=0.8, t=3. Return the 4by1 matrix representing possible stock prices at time 3 (i.e. return S3)

```
S0 = 100; S1 = [125, 80]; S2=[156.25, 100, 64]; S3 = [195.3125, 125, 80, 51.2]
```

I would like to get S3, by calling sapply on an empty matrix, using `s_T` as the function to apply

```
prices = matrix(data=0, nrow =4, ncol=1)
stock_at_time_n = sapply(X = prices, 
    FUN = s_t, tree_path= (ROW#, LENGTH(prices) - ROW#), 
    move_ratio=1.25)
```

Result should be

```
[195.3125, 125, 80, 51.2]
```

*Not concerned if it's a matrix, vector, etc at the moments, as I can just morph it with `as.Whatever_I_want()`*

What is the correct notation for `tree_path= (ROW#, LENGTH(prices) - ROW#)` such that I can get the S3 output?

Comment: In your example are you intending for all iterations to be 'up' movements? If so I cannot reproduce your output with your example. In any case I would think you would want a way to make that dynamic too? If so please update the question. In general to access the index of an R object in an sapply loop you would use `seq_along`.  Something like `sapply(seq_along(prices),function(i) s_t(s_tm=100, tree_path=c(i,length(prices)-i),move_ratio = 1.25)`. Or really the way you are using `sapply` you could just use `1:n`, where `n =4` in your case.

Comment: Yes. the `u_or_d` will always be u. As for movements, since d = 1/u, then it's easy to traverse. If the movement is (4,5) this just means 4up 5down, which would be -1up. Therefore S0*u^-1. This is what the `s_t` function helps with. I should as a call to `s_t` for reference.

Comment: So did I specify the `s_tm` parameter correctly for your example? I must have something specified incorrectly.

Comment: Yes. You should post that as an answer. I realized I have also made this a bit more complicated that it has to be. When, thinking of this as a `Python` list comprehension, your answer made a lot of sense. More importantly, in my main code, I was able to simplify a few definitions/var assignments. Silly `R`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general to access the index of an R object in an `sapply` loop you would use `seq_along`. Something like:

```
sapply(X = seq_along(prices),
       FUN = function(i) {
               s_t(s_tm=100, 
                   tree_path= c (i,length(prices)-i),
                   move_ratio = 1.25)
              })
```

Or really the way you are using `sapply` you could just use `1:n`, where `n = 4` in your case. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Thanks again. I got this to work. In my case, I also switched the indices around so that the highest stock prices would be in index 1 of the matrix.